# Visual Basic: restarting Desktop Windows Manager (DWM)

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows

How do I restart Desktop Windows Manager?
I have already tried:

```
For Each Proc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("DWM")
Proc.Kill()
Next
```

But it gives me an error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: No access

And if I am using it on Notepad:

```
For Each Proc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("NOTEPAD")
Proc.Kill()
Next
```

It works fine.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: As the errors says "No Access" is likely due to your privleges on the system.  This process is likely owned by SYSTEM and is blocking your `Kill()` request.  Are you administrator on the machine?  If you look in TaskMgr, what does the User Name field say next to the DWM process?

Comment: Running in administrator mode helped

Comment: Good, I'm going to post this as the answer then.  Feel free to mark it to show that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error states `No Access` is because the account or privilege level you are using will not allow you to call `Kill()` on that process.

You need to run with elevated privileges, or make sure your account is an Administrator on the machine on which you are trying to run the message.

As it shows in Task Manager - DWM is owned by SYSTEM so only SYSTEM or an Administrator can kill the process.

EDIT:

If you want to elevate the privileges of the program itself, go into your `app.manifest` and change this line:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

To:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: as an administrator, you still need to right click the program and then click "open in administrator mode". can this be done automaticly that it automaticly asks for "do you allow that this program can make changes on your computer"?

Comment: I edited it with a solution to your comment.  If you do not have app.manifest, just add one to the project by right-clicking the project -> add new item -> Application Manifest File.  The code I posted was for C# but it should be similar in Vb.net

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Evan L has written about permissions, you should be using the [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to gracefully restart instead of just killing it.

For example, after adding a reference to `System.ServiceProcess` the following code will restart the DWM (service name `UXSMS`):

```
    Using dwmService As New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("UxSMS")
        dwmService.Stop()
        dwmService.WaitForStatus(ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
        dwmService.Start()
        dwmService.WaitForStatus(ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    End Using
```

Obviously this is omitting any error checking, etc.

Eg. What happens if the service isn't running?

PS. Out of interest, why are you messing with system services? Most DWM related things have [actual API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s and on Windows 8 you can't really disable desktop composition anyway...

Comment: If you stop dwm with the code that i have (or taskmanager) then your screen becomes black for a moment (0.5 - 4 seconds?) and dwm starts automaticy up.

Comment: I don't don't understand what you're trying to say. Are you /trying/ to cause the screen to go black for a short time? When I run it on my machine I also get a brief blank screen.